# ftp server for windows 7 that supports network folder write/read

Tags: windows, ftp, sftp

Am looking for reliable ftp server software for windows 7. I need also something that can give user and password to user and will able to see some network drives folders. Is it possible?

Comment: +1 for FileZilla. I've used it for years and it's very lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

Try FileZilla Server for Windows: http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server That will let you create password protected users with some of these settings: http://www.u4ik.us/public/fz-win.pdf (PDF file with screenshots). It does work on allowing you to attach network drives if you first map them to a letter under the Host. (In the server-computer, map folder XYZ to letter A-Z (one that's not in use) so that accessing drive X (or whatever letter you choose) will indeed open the folder of choice. Then under filezilla, grant a user access to drive X (or which you choose).

If you need more help, ask.